# Column values displacement maintaining pattern

Tags: r, shift

I have the following df (with many columns). How can I force that all values start at 1, maintaining pattern per ID? Example:

```
 input <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
  Obs1 = c(1,1,1,2,2,4,4,5,6,7,2,3,4,4),
  Obs2 = c(2,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
  Obs3 = c(5,6,7,8,9,3,3,3,4,4,1,1,2,2))
```

Desired result

```
result <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
  Obs1 = c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,3),
  Obs2 = c(1,1,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
  Obs3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could group by 'ID' and then `match` the value of all other columns with their `unique` values

```
library(dplyr)
result <- input %>% 
             group_by(ID) %>%
             mutate_all(funs(match(., unique(.))))

all.equal(result, result1, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by ID, and then subtract the minimum (minus 1) of each column within each group:

```
library(dplyr)

input %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Obs1, Obs2, Obs3), funs(. - min(.) + 1))
```